# How to check in a Rules Condition if a specific value of a multi-value field is selected?

Tags: entities, rules

I have a "checkboxes" field that allows the user to select unlimited options. 
How do I check if at least a specific value has been selected?

I am using the Rules module, and when it checks if the 'field has value' it combines all the options. Right now, if both the values "`b`" AND "`c`" are selected, then the action (which checks for the value "`b`") won't be executed.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up creating a "Check a Truth Value" condition with the Rules module. The code below is the one I used.

```
if ($node->field_area_51[0]['value']) {
  foreach ($node->field_area_51 as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[value] == 'b') {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would build a [hook_nodeapi validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) (D6) or a [hook_node_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) (D7) to check if "b" is selected, use dsm to inspect the values of $node. I supposed you're working with the content type page: `$node->type == 'page'` and you field is named `field_options`.
The values are defined like this:

```
a|A option
b|B option
c|C option
```

Code for D7:

```php
function mymodule_node_validate($node, $form) {
  dsm($node);
  $b_selected = FALSE;
  if ($node->type == 'page') {
    foreach($node->field_options[$node->language] as $option) {
      if ($option['value'] == 'b') {
        $b_selected = TRUE;
      }
    }
    if (!$b_selected) {
      form_set_error('field_options', t('Please select at least option B'));
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I'm not sure about the [form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error) for fields

Comment: Thanks tostinni.  Is it bad to use the Rules module for something like this?  I need content to be created based on whether or not 'b' is selected.  I also need certain fields to be prepopulated as well.  That's why I opted to use the Rules module as opposed to writing a somewhat complex function with lots of hooks.

Comment: I'm just not familiar enough with rules and thought this was a perfect exemple for using hook_node_validate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but your custom rule works as implemented: only if value "`b`" is selected, the list of selected values is equal to ... "`b`", while if value "`b`" AND "`c`" are selected, then the list of selected values is NOT equal to ... euh ... "`b`".

To get your rule to work like you want it to work, then you should use these [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Conditions (in the specified order):

- ***Entity has field***, for your "checkboxes" field.
- ***List contains item***, whereas:

  - the list is also about that same "checkboxes" field (since your field allows multiple values, it is also considered as a list).
  - the item you want to check for (if it is contained in the list) is "`b`".

With those 2 Rules Conditions, your Rules Actions should be perform (1) if only value "`b`" was selected, but (2) also if value "`b`" and value "`c`" were ***both*** selected.

For an example Rule (in rules export format) in which you can see this at work, refer to the answer to "[How to check for product taxonomy term in Rules actions (Ubercart)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77976/how-to-check-for-product-taxonomy-term-in-rules-actions-ubercart/218483#218483)". In that case it's about a list of taxonomy terms, but the idea is the same.

PS: even though CCK is rather D6-ish, the same kind of mistake can happen in D7 (which is what my answer is about).