# How to check for product taxonomy term in Rules actions (Ubercart)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, rules, ubercart

I am using Drupal 7 with Ubercart. I am trying to configure to send an email when customer makes a purchase of a product mapped to one particular taxonomy term.

I tried adding actions in a custom rule (created with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)). But there is no such action available to check the product field values or based on taxonomy terms.

Is there any alternative ways to check product fields in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) actions?

Comment: Have you tried the 'Entity has field' condition to check for your taxonomy term?

Comment: I tried that, but I have to check for a value in the field.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @hockey2112 : I think my answer provides a solution now ...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, rather basic, rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format):

```
{ "rules_check_taxonomy_term" : {
    "LABEL" : "Check Taxonomy Term",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert" : [], "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_tags" } },
      { "list_contains" : { "list" : [ "node:field-tags" ], "item" : "21" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "A node containing the tag [node:field_tags] just got created or updated." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is what this rule does:

- Rules Event: After saving new content, After updating existing content
- Rules Conditions:

  - ***Entity has field*** "`field_tags`", which is the machine name of the term reference field I want to check for.
  - ***List contains item*** "node:field-tags" and with Taxonomy term identifier value "`21`" (which is the term id of the term I want to check in this Rules Condition).
- Rules Action: Show a message on the site (which is "*A node containing the tag [node:field_tags] just got created or updated.*" (with `[node:field_tags]` the actual term with term id = `21`).

What is crucial in the above rules example in the context of this question, are the 2 Rules Conditions.

Use the Rules UI to import the above rule in your site. Here are the tweaks you'll need to make it fit your case:

- Replace the Rules Event with an event that matches your "*when customer makes a purchase of a product*".
- Within the Rules Conditions, perform these changes:

  - replace the "node" entity with your entity.
  - replace the machine name of term reference "field_tags", and adapt the "term id" to fit your case.
- Replace the Rules Action by "send an appropriate eMail".