# How to automatically modify a field after saving content?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, rules, actions

I have posted this question on [drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/comment/61257#comment-61257) (via a comment titled "*field modification triggered by saving action*"), but I realized that the thread is more than five years old. So I reproduce here the question made there:

### field modification triggered by saving action

I need to modify a field, but this change has to be triggered when saving the term and it depends on the value of another field, let me explain ...

term

- field 1: filled with options A/B/C
- field 2: `<info>`random_name

I save and if value in

- Field 1 is A, then value in Field 2 must change to "Source: random_name"
- Field 1 is B, then value in Field 2 must change to "Destination: random_name"
- Field 1 is C, then value in Field 2 must change to "Product: random_name"

Note that the label `<info>` is the one that must change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to get this logic implemented. Have a look at my answer to "[How to set the values of some fields depending on the value of a list box?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159293/how-to-set-the-values-of-some-fields-depending-on-the-value-of-a-list-box/192904#192904)".

The rule shown there uses these fields:

- a selection list field with machine name `field_optionlist` (corresponds to your field 1).
- a text field with machine name `field_free_format_text` (corresponds to your field 2).

If you adapt the machine names in that rule (in Rules export format) to the names from your 2 fields, should be straight forward to further tune (customize) it to also match the values as in your case.

However, to make this to work with only 1 rule (instead of writing 3 rules, ie one for each possible value of field 1, so one for "A", one for "B" and one for "C"), you also need the "[Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. That way you could expand the prototype to say dozens of different possible values. For an example using the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module (for which there is not a lot of docu available), refer to my answer to the question "[How to prevent a node being saved when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/how-to-prevent-a-node-being-saved-when-using-the-rules-module/178623#178623)".

**Best practice advise**: the more you start using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, the more you should try to group rules together using the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. Just to keep the entire set of rules manage-able (eg to have related business logic shown on a single Rule UI screen). A good sample of how easy it is to end up with a lot of rules, is what you can see in the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (current [7.x-4.x-rc2](https://www.drupal.org/node/2456653) version):

- It comes with 12 separated rules (not using the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module).
- By using [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional), those 12 could be reduced to only 4 (possibly even less).

Comment: He would have to create 3 different rules, 1 for each scenario. Although, if he wants one rule, he could use [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module.

Comment: To simply this answer: **1)** Add Condition >> Text Comparison >> node:field_name1 >> A.  **2)** Add Action >> Set a Data Value >> node:field_name2 >> random_name  (might have to click switch to direct input mode button)

Comment: @NoSssweat : you're correct (thought that was clear enough from  what's written in the last parg of my other answer). But let me refine my answer here with yes or no using/requiring Conditional rules. BTW: I more and more try to group many rules together these days using the extra module. Just to keep them manage-able.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pierre.Vriens, I'm a little bit lost though, trying to follow you I have done this: 1. Create the Rule PCHRule. 2. Add triggering event: After updating an existing term of vocabulary A. 3 Add condition (on the original question I was using not real data, now I will use it) Text comparison; term:field-relation contains "Child"..... Until here, because I can't figure out what to put in action to repalce in term: field_entrada <p>the_term</p> by <ul>the_term</ul> .... thanks again

Comment: I see now that next step is set a Switch, I selected Data to match cases against, and term:field-entrada:value in the data selector, I'm not suere about this step and I dont know how to finish it....

Comment: @AndrésChandía : if you're still struggling with the exact "Rules Conditions", you may want to look at [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77976/how-to-check-for-product-taxonomy-term-in-rules-actions-ubercart/218483#218483) I posted earlier today. It's about Rules Conditions that check for a specific value of a term reference field. Which is similar I think to what you were trying to achieve, no?