# Get radio field value in data selector in rules

Tags: 7, rules

In content type form, I have a select list as radio with two values "Complaint" and "Feedback".

After content type save, I need to send email if "Complaint" is checked to complaint@web.com and if "Feedback" is checked then send email to feedback@web.com

I know how to do that with text field (e.g **field-text-field** is empty or not) but not yet found any solution with radio buttons.

Note: I have installed the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, and also enabled its sub-modules **Rules UI** and **Rules Scheduler**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1

To get your rule to work like you want it to work, for the "Complaint"-part you should use these [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Conditions (in the specified order):

- ***Entity has field***, for your "select list" field.
- ***List contains item***, whereas:

  - the list is also about that same "select list" field.
  - the item you want to check for (if it is contained in the list) is "`Complaint`".

With those 2 Rules Conditions, your Rules Action to be performed is to send the eMail to complaint@web.com.

For an example Rule (in rules export format) in which you can see this at work, refer to the answer to "[How to check for product taxonomy term in Rules actions (Ubercart)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77976/how-to-check-for-product-taxonomy-term-in-rules-actions-ubercart/218483#218483)". In that case it's about a list of taxonomy terms, but the idea is the same.

#### Step 2

Create a similar rule by reepeating Step 1, but now for "Feedback".

#### Step 3 (optional)

If you'd be willing to also use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, you could merge the rules from Step 1 and 2 in a single rule, ie because this module allows you to include Rules Conditions as part of Rules Actions.

Comment: I found this helpful. At first I tried  a simple data comparison, but it wasn't properly getting the value of the check boxes. After following your details from step 1 I got it working.

Comment: @Draevelop merci for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this writing a custom code here is one solution:
while saving the node call a submit function

```
$form['#submit'] = 'your function';
```

Check the value of the radio button and provide the $to parameter accordingly.
then use the snippet below to send the custom email  through your module

```
$module = 'module_name';
$key = 'key for the email';
$to = 'mailaddress';// which you set above according to the selected radio value
$language = language_default();
$from = 'from_email_address';
$send = FALSE;
$subject = 'subject line';
$body = 'body of the email';
$params = array(
'subject' => $subject,
'body' => $body,
);
$message = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
$message['subject'] = $subject;
$message['body'] = array();
$message['body'][] = $body;
// Retrieve the responsible implementation for this message.
$system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
// Format the message body.
$message = $system->format($message);
// Send e-mail.
$message['result'] = $system->mail($message);
if ($message['result'] == 1) {
drupal_set_message(t('Mail has been sent to the user'), 'status');
}
else {
drupal_set_message(t('Mail was not sent'), 'error');
};
```